# How to set input mask for EditText with regular expression?

Tags: android

I read about [regular expression](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/package-summary) in java, if I understood correctly,I can check a string with some my regulars of regex.
I want to set input mask (phone,credit card,email...) for EditText:

[image: Credit card - regex "###########"]

[image: Phone number - regex "############"]

Is it possible to control input type mask of EditText with regex?